# Python, Selenium, web tab assistance

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

There is a web site, I can get the data I need with Python / Selenium (I am new to Selenium and Python)
on the web page there are TABS, I can get the data on the first tab as that one is active by default, I cannot get data on the second TAB.

I attached an image: this shows the data in the overview TAB, I want to get the data in the Fundamental TAB as well. This web page is investing.com.

As for the code: (I did not use everything yet, some were added for future use)

```
     from time import sleep, strftime
     import pandas as pd
     from selenium import webdriver
     from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
     import smtplib
     from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

     url = 'https://www.investing.com/stock-screener/?
```

`sp=country::6|sector::a|industry::a|equityType::a|exchange::a|last::1,1220|avg_volume::250000,15950000%3Ceq_market_cap;1'`

```
     chrome_path = 'E:\\BackUp\\IT\\__Programming\\Python\\_Scripts\\_Ati\\CSV\\chromedriver'
     driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
     #driver = webdriver.Chrome()
     driver.implicitly_wait(10)
     driver.get(url)

     my_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@data-column-name='name_trans']")
     my_symbol = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@data-column-name='viewData.symbol']")
     my_last = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@data-column-name='last']")
     my_change = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@data-column-name='pair_change_percent']")
     my_marketcap = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@data-column-name='eq_market_cap']")
     my_volume = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@data-column-name='turnover_volume']")
```

The code Above all works.

The Xpath of the second tab does not work.
PE Ratio is in the second tab. (in the fundamentals)

I tried the three:

`my_peratio = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id="resultsTable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]")`

`my_peratio = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='resultsTable']")`

`my_peratio = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@data-column-name='eq_pe_ratio']")`

There are no error messages but the string 'my_peratio' han nothing in it. It is empty.

I really appreciate if you could direct me to the right direction.

Thanks a lot

Ati

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uzSS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the data which is shown on the second tab is loaded dynamically.
In that case, you have to click on the second tab to show the data first.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("selector_for_second_tab").click()
```

After that it should be possible to get the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciated. I will try